# How many configurations are possible in a Rubik's cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube

A Rubik's cube has 54 visible facelets. There are 6 colours and each colour has 9 facelets. How many configurations are possible? How do you find that?

Answer (score 1):

Noting that there are indeed some restrictions on the number of edges (12) and corners (8) of the cube we have, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik's_Cube#Permutations), about 43 quintillion possibilities:

$$8!3^7\frac{12!}{2}2^{11}=43252003274489856000$$

The actual explanation as to why these numbers is on the Wikipedia link provided above:

> There are 8! ways to arrange the corner cubes.  Each corner has three
>   possible orientations, although only seven  (of eight) can be oriented
>   independently;  the orientation of the eighth (final) corner depends
>   on the preceding seven, giving 3^7 possibilities.  There are 12!/2
>   ways to arrange the edges, restricted from 12! because edges must be
>   in an even permutation exactly when the corners are. Eleven edges can
>   be flipped independently, with the flip of the twelfth depending on
>   the preceding ones, giving 2^11 possibilities.

**Old (and wrong) answer**

Using combinatorial numbers you have that the possible orderings correspond to the multiset permutation of the set:

$$S=\{C_1,...,C_1,C_2,...,C_2,...,C_9,...C_9\}$$

where $C_i$ denotes one element of colour $i$. This set has $9\cdot 6=54$ elements and 9 elements for each colour, then the number of possible ordenations follows:

$${54 \choose 9,9,9,9,9,9}=\frac{54!}{9!9!9!9!9!9!}\approx 1\cdot 10^{38}$$

Comment: Some of the facelets are connected by an edge or corner. That has to be taken into account.

Comment: @Casper true. I'll try to recalculate it taking these restrictions into account.